# File.Delete and Directory.Delete network performance

Tags: c#, file-io

Does anybody know how `File.Delete` and `Directory.Delete` execute?

I mean: what happens if assuming I were to delete some files/folders over the network and the network is considerably slow?

Would it complete as fast as it would be locally? Would it consume more bandwidth than say move files to that network location?

Comment: How could a delete operation "consume more bandwidth" than a move operation? Exactly what kind of bandwidth are you talking about?

Comment: I know it's nonsense to compare move and delete. But just would like to know how much execution time delete compares to a move. I should have made it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be as fast a it would be locally. It would be slow, with a latency that depends on your network conditions.

You don't send your `Delete` command "remotely" to a "smart end" which knows how to, say, delete a folder as an atomic operation. Your code actually runs against the network location which is "dumb" and deletes file-by-file.

As for your last question, `Delete` is almost always faster than `Move`. When you move files across disks (and of course across network locations), it's actually a copy operation (with a 'delete' at the end of it).

Answer (score 1):

They both call into the win32 api to do work,

This is from reflector 7:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public static void Delete(string path)
{
    if (path == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    }
    string fullPathInternal = Path.GetFullPathInternal(path);
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, new string[] { fullPathInternal }, false, false).Demand();
    if (!Win32Native.DeleteFile(fullPathInternal))
    {
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (errorCode != 2)
        {
            __Error.WinIOError(errorCode, fullPathInternal);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would it complete as fast as it would be locally?

No, it is quite slow because there is no delete directory in windows - Directory.Delete lists all files over the network then deletes them. Same as windows explorer .Depending on teh amount of files this can take time. Deleting 30.000 files is first listing them then 30.000 individual delete operations.

> Would it consume more bandwidth than say move files to that network location?

No, it would not because the files are never moved. Copying the files is always a lot slower then deleting them.

Comment: There is the `rd`-command in the shell for deleting directories. I don't know why the GUI doesn't use the same functionality - other than perhaps to give the users a chance to click cancel.

Answer (score 0):

They both run synchronously - that is, they both wait for the task to complete before returning control to the caller. So, calling them to delete files or directories over a network would take longer.

Answer (score 0):

They basically use the corresponding native Win32 APIs which means the performance is nearly the same as with a native application (no real difference between .NET and native)...

Basically all file I/O is slower when done on network drive/paths/shares - so: yes, they will be slower compared to the same operation executed locally. How much slower depends on several aspects including (but not limited to) network latency, server, file system performance etc.

Comment: Pretty much not the question, and yes, it is a lot slower to delete over the network than locally.

Comment: @TomTom I suspect you did not read the second paragraph of my answer ?

Comment: @TomTom another point: the first part of the OP's question is about "how they execute" which I answered in the first paragraph and the rest of the question was about performane which I answered in the second paragraph...

Answer (score 0):

They wrap calls through Win32 api.

Check out their function through a free tool here.
[ILSPY](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)

Or the paid alternative [reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)